# Deleting two rows based on successful deletion of another row which is based on a column condition - Sybase

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sybase, sqlanywhere

I am trying to delete two rows based on only if another 3rd row is deleted. Now, the catch here is, the 3rd row has a condition where only for value "A" of column "MAN", it should delete that corresponding row.

i am doing it in Sybase (SQL Anywhere using Interactive SQL IDE).

I am unable to use @@ROWCOUNT.

Could someone please give me the query for this or how to achieve this please.

### ALGORITHM:

DELETE FROM EFS
WHERE NAME='MAN' AND VAL='A'

If (DeleteSuccessful)
{
DELETE FROM EFS
WHERE NAME='MAN_1' AND NAME='MAN_2'
}

I want to achieve this in a single query in Sybase.

### ALTERNATIVE APPROACH:

I can also think of achieve this by first checking the value of VAL column and if it is XX, then I can write a query to delete all 3 rows using WHERE NAME ='MAN AND NAME ='MAN_1' AND NAME ='MAN_2'. this is also one approach. But don't know how to do it using syntax in Sybase in a single query/

Comment: Your question is not clear. "if another 3rd row is deleted.".. can you clear your question a bit so we can help?

Comment: @user1768024: I need to basically delete 3 rows. How? The business case is like, I want to first delete a row based on certain value say "A" of its column "Man". Which means, I use a simple delete query using where condition. Now this row is deleted, all good. But what about other two rows? I need to delete other two rows based on, only if this first row is deleted. Else, the other two rows shouldn't be deleted.

Comment: Do you have condition for rest two rows?

Comment: @user1768024: Condition as in, only one condition in where. Its simple mate. However, I am restricted with no use of Stored Proc in Sybase. I am first time writing query. Do you have any idea how to implement it without using SP/Function and with what features are supported by Sybase (SQL Anywhere using SQL Interactive IDE)

Comment: @user1768024: Mate, I myself has written a simple algorithm which is updated in my question above, but struggling for keywords that is supported in Sybase for a single query. Surprised, you haven't understood this.

Comment: I can help with query but sure your question is not very clear. If it is very simple why you not deleting all 3 rows at once like DELETE from table where A = "MAN" and (REST QUERY)? Is this something I am thinking out of scope?

Comment: @user1768024: I have give my algorithm. Remember, I can achieve this via SP easily in SQL, but I am using Sybase mate, I am not able to use SP in our project as per guidelines. Secondly, I can check if first delete query succeeds using @@ROWCOUNT and if so, I can continue deleting other two rows, but for this, I ain't sure of the syntax as @@ROWCOUNT is not supported in Sybase.

Comment: @user1768024: It is my alrogithm. I can also think of achieve this by first checking the value of VAL column and if it is XX, then I can write a query to delete all 3 rows using WHERE NAME ='MAN AND NAME ='MAN_!' AND NAME ='MAN_2'. this is also one approach. But don't know how to do it using sytax in Sybase in a single query/

Comment: Sorry Mate maybe I am not right person to help. I am good in SQL, but you talking about something else. Normally you need to create own algorithm when queries are very complex and in your case it very clear that the thing you want to achieve is very simple.

Comment: Try DELETE FROM tableName WHERE NAME IN ("MAN", "MAN_2", "MAN_3");

Comment: @user1768024: It is very simple mate using SP, but I ordered to use a single query as in our 20 years big project, we never used SP as per client rule. Can you help me? I gave two algorithms above.

Comment: @user1768024: Mate, are you aware? All these MAN, MAN_!, MAN_2 are different rows and have different values for VAL Column, hence I couldn't use it. I thought of this only first, yet I appreciate your response :/

Comment: SP allow you to run sql query or not? Try query that will delete all rows which contains list of strings in bracket. Let me know if it works!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. I CANNOT USE SP as per CLIENT MANAGER ORDER.

Comment: @user1768024: Remember, @@ROWCOUNT is supported in Sybase too. But dont know how to frame single query using this to check if deleted first row, then delete other two rows

Comment: Yes, I know you have all MAN, MAN_!, MAN_2 in different rows in column VAL. That query will delete all rows WHERE NAME(VAL) in list of comma separated strings .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54718/discussion-between-user1768024-and-divine).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check if these values exists and do it in one query

```
DELETE FROM EFS 
  WHERE (NAME='MAN' AND VAL='A')
        OR
        ( 
          (NAME='MAN_1' AND NAME='MAN_2')
          AND 
          EXISTS (SELECT * FROM EFS WHERE NAME='MAN' AND VAL='A')
         )
```

Comment: Thanks, but your query would be wrong I guess? I already had my query framed by myself that's reather simple IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM EFS WHERE NAME='MAN' AND VAL='A') THEN DELETE FROM EFS WHERE NAME ='MAN' or NAME='MAN_2' OR NAME='MAN_3' END IF

Comment: Can you tell me the difference between yours and my query? I feel mine is better.

Answer (score 1):

I believe both you and valex are both getting the correct result, but your syntax is a little off. Also better to use IN vs. OR for performance.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM EFS WHERE NAME='MAN' AND VAL='A') 
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM EFS WHERE NAME IN ('MAN','MAN_2','MAN_3')
END
```

And, I think you can use @@rowcount, perhaps you don't consider this a single statement approach but it also works, e.g.

```
select * from tempdb..test
irecord
1
2
3
99

declare @deleted INT
delete from tempdb..test where irecord = 3
select @deleted = @@rowcount
if @deleted > 0
begin
  print 'deletion detected'
  delete from tempdb..test where irecord IN (1,2)
end
else
  print 'no deletion detected'

1 row(s) affected.
1 row(s) affected.
deletion detected
2 row(s) affected.

select * from tempdb..test
irecord
99
```

Comment: Crizzo, thank you, the second method is ruled out as I said, because we need single query as it is all upgrade scripts and as per practise for 20 years :) And, the "IN" doesn't work here I am afraid, in Sybase is it not supported?